# What are the best practices for testing bulk email sends?

Tags: email, testing, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

What are the best practices (or even just *any* way at all) of testing bulk email sends?

I'm using the Twilio [SendGrid C# library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) with the built-in [CreateMultipleEmailsToMultipleRecipients](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/MailHelper.cs#L173) function. Here's [an example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#send-multiple-emails-to-multiple-recipients) of that function in the context of some code.

SendGrid does not appear to allow me to just send myself (i.e. a single email address) a ton of emails, it ends up only delivering only a few.

The end goal is that I want to see that my code is using the CreateMultipleEmailsToMultipleRecipients function correctly, and that it works for 100 users, then 1000 users (which is the supposed limit of that function IIRC).

Comment: Can you try sending to yourself using plus addressing (example+test1@example.com) so that it's not just the same email address? What are you expecting to discover from this testing and from the difference between sending 100 and 1000 emails? [The docs tell you that the limit of this API call is 1000 recipients](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/limitations).

Comment: I will try the + and . trick, but I suspect the limit here is that the email provider forces the emails into a state of deferral. Maybe I could change the from address, hmm...

I am hoping to discover that this code works in a Saas web application context. I should be able to do multiple calls on the CreateMultipleEmailsToMultipleRecipients function, with 1000 or less recipients per call, which should allow up many thousands of recipients to be processed, but it'd be nice to test it.

Comment: I mean, the docs say that a single API request can send up to 1000 emails. And sending multiple API requests will allow you to multiply that 1000 by the number of requests. Although, it is normally easier to use SendGrid Marketing Campaigns for something like this, that way you can upload your contacts and send them all an email with a single API request.

Comment: We're using the bulk email feature to allow our customers within our SaaS to be able to send bulk email to their own user base. So that's the reason why we couldn't use SendGrid Marketing Campaigns, and also the reason we'd like to be able to actually see if CreateMultipleEmailsToMultipleRecipients actually works for 100 users, 999 users, 1000 users, then do multiple calls to CreateMultipleEmailsToMultipleRecipients, etc. These are all specific details of our context, but I'm still not finding even a generic answer to "How to test bulk email" just in general, under any framework.

Comment: Your issue is more, "how do I test receiving 1000 emails to 1000 different addresses?" rather than "how do I test sending 1000 emails?" and I'm afraid I don't have a great answer for that.